# Arduino Uno ESD ruggedness

Tags: arduino, protection, esd

I want to route one of the Arduino's digital output pins out of a device, to interface with other instruments via a several meter long coax cable. Typically, I would implement measures against ESD for such a use case. However, I am wondering if this is redundant, because the bare Arduino boards don't seem to care much about ESD. The question is somewhat academic I admit, because I have not much to lose when simply placing the ESD protection anyway. But I am interested why this is not always seen.

The Arduino Uno R4 has no additional ESD protection components on its board. [The digital pins are directly routed](https://docs.arduino.cc/resources/schematics/ABX00080-schematics.pdf) into the microcontroller R7FA4M1AB3CFM. The [datasheet for the latter](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/ra4m1-group-datasheet) indicates no special ESD ruggedness. Searches for "kV", "HBM" or "61000" turned up nothing. A search for "ESD" only revealed a note, that ESD is bad.

The absolute maximum ratings do not indicate any special ruggedness either. A maximum fault current is not given, so I assume it to be minimal:

[image]

Still, I observe people handling the board with no special care, touching pins, with power on or off, easily generating voltages of 100s or 1000s of volts and the board survives this without issues.

So ESD seems to be no problem for the Arduino to such a degree that the makers of Arduino didn't bother to implement onboard ESD protection on a product that is obviously mass-produced. So I have an inner conflict: my intuition to require ESD protection for my use case and my other intuition to trust the careful design choices of a reliable mass-produced Arduino board.

Is extra ESD protection needed for my use case? If so, why is it not needed for other use cases like millions of students tempering with it on their fiber carpet?

Comment: The table you posted is completely irrelevant - what supply the MCU can handle has nothing to do with ESD ruggedness. ESD parameters are either specified as tolerance in kV or in peak pulse power expressed in W given some timing characteristics of the pulse.

Comment: @Lundin Is it likely that such information would be missing in this 131 page datasheet? Or is it rather likely that I can't find it using the terms stated in my question?

Comment: If the manufacturer knows that the part is crap, they usually don't mention it. If they know that they added rugged protection diodes, they will want to brag about it. Overall Renesas has a whole lot better reputation than AVR though.

Comment: @Lundin I share your implicit conclusion, but that leaves me wondering: If the ESD protection of the MCU is mediocre at best, how are these boards so sturdy in practise?

Comment: Who said they are sturdy? They are toy boards for hobbyists. There will be some manner of ESD protection diodes in all modern IC, but the documentation for this part is mediocre. Reading Renesas docs tend to end up with wild goose chase after a different document... whoever split up the documentation in most files wins a price, apparently...

Comment: @Lundin My observation of basically no board failing despite inadvertent use lead me to believe that they are sturdy. The [STM32G0](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32g031k8.pdf) used on STM's Nucleo board does indicate ESD ratings and also an abs. max. rating for injected IO current through the steering diodes (5 mA). What's your gut feeling? Do Renesas merely not bother to test/spec/document well, or would their parts be markedly worse?

Comment: My guts say that they do have this specified somewhere, but the document is either a pain to find or you have to prompt them for it through support channels.

Comment: @Lundin Could you perhaps tone down the rants? Language like "part is crap", "toy boards", etc. helps no one.

Comment: @marcelm We do have an obligation as engineers to point out that these boards are wildly unsuitable for professional use. All the diverse "Arduino experiments" are plain dangerous. They aren't even suitable for learning either, since students using them will pick up tons of bad practices designed into the platform.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not saying I disagree with your message, but I do disagree with the tone. "unsuitable for professional use because X" is much better than "crap toy boards grumble" ;)

Comment: Arduino boards are basically the microprocessor slapped onto a pcb along with the minimum circuitry required to make it operate and to download code to it. I don’t know of too many microcontrollers that have sufficient ESD tolerance to connect an unprotected wire to the outside world. They may survive a surprising amount of abuse, but the effects may take time to show themselves. I’d suggest adding suitable protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESD rating isn't a guarantee of failure beyond a threshold.  It is a guarantee of survival below a threshold.

Or, even more specifically, it might be a sampling point, wherein some articles have been tested at such-and-such level, and seemed to survive.  I'm not sure about IC ratings (I don't have the base standards), but suspect they're done on a design-assurance level; equipment is certainly tested on such a sampling basis however (i.e. you run one unit through EMC testing and it passes or fails).  Perhaps someone involved in IC design can offer context on this.

Anyway, I've seen plenty of things get zapped by way more than they deserve to handle, and, at least without digging closely (monitoring supply consumption / pin leakage, testing pin characteristics like exact ESD diode voltages, recovery time, hFE to adjacent pins / through supply, etc.), they at least seem to continue functioning.  But momentary function is not a guarantee of continued function, or of robustness for every part (of the same type) ever produced.

Intermittent operation is a typical consequence.  Sometimes a part is damaged, but recovers over time; others survive but later fail.  Maybe it comes and goes.  Diffusion of atoms in the affected zone can turn either way, and partially melted or vaporized conductors can migrate, break or reform.  Most often it survives or doesn't, but there are random partial cases and you don't really know for sure.

If a chip doesn't specify ESD ratings, it's possible it's a 1kV default, specified in a rarely-seen (if you're not a manufacturer) JESD, JEDEC or other standard.  It might also be specified in a common document somewhere; check the quality section perhaps?

I would just as well decline to use a part that doesn't specify its ESD level.  Not that that's helpful to users of such a board...

As for why they didn't?  Expense, I'm sure. If the board is cheap enough, who cares.  Arduino stuff I suppose I would consider somewhat disposable.  It's also arguably development materials to be operated by authorized technicians and therefore not required to meet ratings.  (As commodity items, they are still CE rated, though I haven't checked what they've actually rated them for; this will be, in part, in their filings/disclosures.)